# AVPlayer doesn't play stream in local network

Tags: video-streaming, avplayer, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I programmed a simple streaming-server in Java which allows me to stream media files over HTTP. It works perfectly fine when i open the stream on a computer or a smartphone in the same network. To be abled to open the stream on my Samsung Smart TV, i tried to make a little app with Tizen Studio. Since the video-tag isn't abled to play many different formats, i used the AVPlayer. When i open a video file from a website (for example: http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4) in my app, it works. But when i try to open the stream of my mediastreamer (for example: http://192.168.1.101:9876/stv) in my local network, it doesn't show anything besides the AVPlayer-controls, no matter how long i wait for something to happen.

What is the problem here? There shouldn't be much of a difference between the video from the website and my stream except the size of the videos. I tried to stream many differnt video-formats, and none of them works, so the failure can't be the format.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you see the Config.xml Declarations section at: http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/guides/multimedia/common/using-avplay ?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in config.xml

```
<access origin='*' subdomains='true'/>
```

Comment: Hey @Frankiegi, did it fix your issue?